# ansible playbook of playbooks with variables

Tags: variables, ansible

I'm not even sure if this is possible..

I know you can have a playbook that calls other playbooks..

IE:

```
---
# MasterPlaybook.yml

- include: playbook1.yml
  when: some_var == "true"

- include: playbook2.yml
  when: someother_var == "true"
```

and this will work if I call MasterPlaybook.yml and pass in the Vars..

BUT I want to include the vars from some other yml
for example here is myvars.yml

```
  some_var: "true"
  someother_var: "false"
  Other_var: "Foo"
```

So if I want this included in a playbook1.yml I simply add..

```
---
- name: Script Play use variables to get and push out the code
  hosts: somegroup
  remote_user: "some user"
  vars:
    url: 'The url of the build'
    buildNumber: 'the build number'
    jobName: 'passed in job name'
  vars_files:
    - ~/myvars.yml
  serial: 1
```

and it will pull in the vars..

My question is how do I do this in the masterplaybook.yml so that I don't have to pass in the vars?

and while we are at it.. are there any good examples of a master playbook?  (or a playbook of playbooks)

Answer (score 5):

You can specify vars as part of the include statements. This is what I do for some of my projects.

```
---

- include: playbook1.yml
  vars:
      some_var: "true"
      someother_var: "false"
      Other_var: "Foo"
  when: some_var == "true"

- include: playbook2.yml
  when: someother_var == "true"
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at **roles** in ansible. They are a more structured way for the "playbook of playbooks" concept. There you can define global variables in the "master" playbook and variables within the sub-playbooks http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_roles.html.

You can also have a look at the  [example playbooks](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-examples) to see how roles are used and structured.

Comment: for some reason Roles is just not making sense to me.. could you recommend a good tutorial?

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/leucos/ansible-tuto . In step 12 the tutorial explains roles. I recomend to read the entire tutorial, because the concept of roles is just an organized way to write reusable steps of a playbook which belongs thematically together (like steps to install and configure apache, mysql ...). Afterwards you can look at the link above for the example playbooks to see some role as they are used in real life situations.